# Get pointer (IntPtr) of int value

Tags: c#

How I can get an Intptr pointer of integer value?

I was trying to do that it work. Are any other variants?

```
GCHandle gCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc (size, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr sizePtr = gCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject ();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only objects of a reference types can be pinned, *int* is a value type.

You can get a pointer to an int that's a local variable in a method:

```
unsafe void foo() {
   int value = 42;
   int* ptrToValue = &value;
   // etc, do not return the pointer!!
   //...
}
```

Comment: **NOTE:** In general you won't return the pointer, but you may return its value, e.g. `return *ptrToValue;` - don't forget to replace `void` by `int` if you want to do that.  Of course, you can also return `int*`  via `return ptrToValue;` but then you can only call foo() from inside another unsafe function/method which uses the pointer being returned by `foo`. Otherwise you'll get the compiler error `CS0214 Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context`.